# Scala - complex conditional pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a statement I want to express, that in C pseudo-code would look like this:

```
switch(foo):
    case(1)
        if(x > y) {
            if (z == true)
                doSomething()
            }
            else {
                doSomethingElse()
            }
        return doSomethingElseEntirely()

    case(2)
        essentially more of the same
```

Is a nice way possible with the scala pattern matching syntax?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to handle multiple conditions in a single `match` statement, you can also use *guards* that allow you to specify additional conditions for a case:

```
foo match {    
  case 1 if x > y && z => doSomething()
  case 1 if x > y => doSomethingElse()
  case 1 => doSomethingElseEntirely()
  case 2 => ... 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually match what the OP wrote.  The control flow is different; on `x>y&&z`, the OP executes `doSomething()`, `return doSomethingElseEntirely()`, while yours returns `doSomething()` alone.

Comment: @Rex - Good point, thanks. I didn't quite get it because OP's code is missing some opening and closing curly braces. Anyway, it should be easy to fix the body accordingly.

Comment: To me, this doesn't make it clear the x > y test is common to the first two branches. There's nothing inherently wrong with if/then/else and in this case, it's clearer (IMO).

Comment: @Paul I agree, but it was the OP to ask for this kind of solution! :)

Comment: I fail to use guards in the exception handling

Comment: I know this is old, but I will say that in some ways I prefer the pattern match -- it lays out that there are three paths and that the paths each have a set of necessary conditions. It emphasizes the branch rather than the common elements of the conditions, which in some cases might be clearer.